# Элемент 2-х блоков в БЭМ

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, бэм

У меня есть следующий html-код:

```
<header class="filter">
    <h1 class="filter__title title-default">Каталог</h1>
    <div class="filter__parameter dropdown">
        <button class="filter__toggle dropdown__toggle">По жанрам</button>
        <ul class="filter__values-list dropdown__content">
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 1</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 2</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 3</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 4</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 5</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 6</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 7</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 8</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 9</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Жанр 10</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter__parameter dropdown">
        <button class="filter__toggle dropdown__toggle">Сначала популярные</button>
        <ul class="filter__values-list dropdown__content">
            <li class="filter__value">Популярные</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Новые</li>
            <li class="filter__value">Законченные</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Мне кажется, что он не совсем корректен относительно БЭМ. В том смысле, что элементы внутри dropdown являются как элементами блока filter, так и элемента dropdown, и вроде как это не допустимо. Но мне нужно реализовать как стили dropdown, так и стили filter на этих элементах. Как мне поступить?

Comment: как вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/whfuxc4k/1/

Comment: @soledar10 , Там все равно есть элементы filter внутри блока dropdown.

Comment: о каких элементах filter идет речь?

Comment: @soledar10 , filter__toggle, filter__values-list

Comment: в бэм это называется миксы - https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#микс

Comment: @soledar10 , Про миксы в курсе, в том плане, что элемент внутри блока может также сам являться блоком. Но чтобы внутри этого блока присутствовали элементы родительского блока, также допустимо?

Comment: вполне, можно использовать